# Adding minimize and maximize buttons to windows in Gnome

Tags: gnome, gnome-3, gnome-shell

I have added the `minimize` and `maximize` buttons as described [here](http://geekum.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/how-to-move-close-button-in-debian-gnome-shell-to-left-like-ubuntu/).
I tried both command line and GUI options.

They don't add...
And when in GUI I see a red marker stating "The key has no schema"

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: Read the comments below that post. They give instructions for more modern versions of at least Fedora and Ubuntu (you didn't say what distribution you were using.) Also, this isn't programming related, so it would be better to ask on Super User.

Comment: @ptomato  +1 or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok,

```
gsettings set  org.gnome.shell.overrides button-layout ':minimize,maximize,close'
```

Does the trick.